# What information does Titanfall save locally?

Tags: titanfall

I haven't played Titanfall in months, so I'd like to delete it and get the 56 gigs it's currently taking up on my HDD back. I'd like to keep my regen level and other things in case I want to reinstall the game sometime and pop back in for some good ol' Titan punchfests. I know that the screenshots are saved locally, so I can back those up easily, but I don't know if there's anything that else that is. Considering the game's tied to Origin and there's no offline single player campaign, I'm guessing most things are serverside/in Origin's cloud, but I'm not sure.

This is what I'm primarily concerned about:

- Regen level
- Titan loadouts
- Burn Cards
- Challenge progress
- Insignias and Insignia progress

Considering the length of time it's been since I played, I may be forgetting things, so any additional information would be welcome.

Comment: If you have access to another machine, you could simply install Titanfall on that machine and check what was saved and what is missing.
Generally I assume (and expect) everything you mentioned is saved somewhere but not locally.

Comment: @r0estir0bbe I unfortunately don't have another one I could install it on that has enough room to do so to test and I don't want to risk losing stuff right now by uninstalling my own version. :/